# Python. Can I use cv2.setMouseCallback() in OpenCV through PyQt5?

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt

Using opencv in python 3 I can bind mouse events to a created windows `cv2.setMouseCallback()`. Using some extra function I can return the mouse cursor position in pixel coordinates

I would like to know if I can use the same but using now PyQt5. I mean `cv2.setMouseCallback()` and return the cursor position, and draw a rectangle to select some object, like I can do it using only opencv too`.

The objetive is make a GUI app to tracking object using opencv and another libraries

Comment: Is your intention to get mouse events on a window in PyQt5? Qt provides an easy way to get the mouse position in a `QWidget` or `QWindow`. Look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) for example

Comment: my intention is to do a object tracking selecting the object using the mouse. I can do it using opencv and dlib, but I would like to create a GUI.
I am not expert only a beginner, but I can see that position of pixels I can draw a rectangle
dlib.rectangle(upleftX,upleftY,  bottomrightX, bottomrightY)

So if I can capture return the mouse position from PyQt Widget I could do the same?